# Angular 1.x $q to Angular 2.0 beta

Tags: angularjs, service, promise, angular

Wanted to convert following service to Angular 2 Service. I am  using google api here. The main problem I am getting is to returning the Promise as its not similar as Angular 1.x.

```
 getLoginStatus: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: dataStore.getData('CLIENT_ID'), scope: dataStore.getData('SCOPES'), immediate: true},function(response){
      var res = {};
           res = response;
           deferred.resolve(res);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Angular 2 uses RxJS 5 [`Observables`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS) for this:

Here is a 1:1 translation of your code:

```
getLoginStatus: function () {
      return new Observable(function(observer) {
      gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: dataStore.getData('CLIENT_ID'), scope: dataStore.getData('SCOPES'), immediate: true},function(response){
           observer.next(response);
           observer.complete();
      });
 }
```

Comment: (For what it's worth, you can still use promises just fine).

Comment: i have tried to use this but not succeed. i have never used Observer. i am using something like this                                                          getLoginStatus() {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: this._dataStore.getData('CLIENT_ID'), scope: this._dataStore.getData('SCOPES'), immediate: true }, resolve));
    }