# Angular2 Observable - Await multiple function calls before proceeding

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular-promise

I am trying to improve my knowledge of Angular2 by migrating an application currently written in Angular1/AngularJS.

One feature in particular has me stumped. I am trying to replicate a feature where a calling function waits to proceed until the function it is calling has completed a loop of promises. In AngularJS, the function I am calling looks basically like this:

```
this.processStuff = function( inputarray, parentnodeid ) {
    var promises = [];
    var _self = this;
    angular.forEach( inputarray , function( nodeid ) {

        switch ( parentnodeid )
        {
            case ‘AAA’ : var component = _self.doMoreStuff( nodeid, parentnodeid ); break;
            case ‘BBB’ : var component = _self.doMoreStuff( nodeid, parentnodeid ); break;
            case ‘CCC’ : var component = _self.doMoreStuff( nodeid, parentnodeid ); break;
            default    : var component = null;
        }
        promises.push( component );
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
};
```

It contains a `forEach` loop that calls another function (`doMoreStuff`) that also returns a promise, and it stores all those returned promises in an array.

With AngularJS, when I call `processStuff` in another function, I could count on the system waiting until `processStuff` completed before entering into the code in the then block:

```
service.processStuff( arraying, parentidarg )
       .then(function( data ) {
              ...
```

The caller of `processStuff` waits for all `doMoreStuff` invocations to complete until the caller of `processStuff` enters into its `then` block.

I am unsure of how to achieve this with Angular2 and Observables. I can see from these posts that to mimic promises, Observables basically just use `subscribe()` instead of `then()`:

[Angular 1.x $q to Angular 2.0 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436429/angular-1-x-q-to-angular-2-0-beta)

But how do I await all invocations in the `forEach` loop to complete before my application can proceed?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I have been doing this with forkJoin

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.get('./friends.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
  this.http.get('./customer.json').map((res: Response) => res.json())
)
.subscribe(res => this.combined = {friends: res[0].friends, customer: res[1]});
```

Some more info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

Comment: the argument for the forkJoin can be an array? Could you please show an example where you are iterating with a for loop to populate this "array". I am not certain if the loop is inside or outside the new Observable block and how to use observer.next(); and observer.complete();

Comment: see here for specific import instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581471/angular2-http-is-missing-map-function/34581771#34581771

Comment: Yes, it can be an array: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

Comment: also: import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'

Comment: Why did the Rx team choose the name `forkJoin`? Why not call it something descriptive like `with` or `when`? `forkJoin` is not clear what it does

Comment: you can look up the fork/join model.

Answer (score 4):

**In RxJS v6 and later you can do this more eloquently with *zip*.**

```
    import { zip } from 'rxjs';

    const promise1 = yourSvc.get(yourFavoriteAPI.endpoint1);
    const promise2 = yourSvc.get(yourFavoriteAPI.endpoint2);

    const promises = zip(promise1, promise2);

    promises.subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
      console.log(data1);
      console.log(data2);
    });
```

While the result is the same, I find `zip` preferable to `forkJoin` since `zip` is more universal and can handle new values from the observables.

Details from the [rxjs documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip):

> The **zip** operator will subscribe to all inner observables, waiting for
> each to emit a value. Once this occurs, all values with the
> corresponding index will be emitted. This will continue until at least
> one inner observable completes.