# How do you return new Observable(function(observer) { ... with RxJS v5?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to replace all the promises that my functions return with Observables. From this post, I learned that I should no longer use "new Observable" [Observable.forkJoin and array argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676451/observable-forkjoin-and-array-argument)

What is the RxJS v5 syntax to achieve this as such to achieve asynchronous waiting?

```
thirdFunction() {

    let _self = this;

    return new Observable(function(observer) {

        ...

        observer.next( responseargs );
        observer.complete();
    });
}
```

Thank you greatly for help you can offer.

Comment: I guess he means the creation functions listed in http://reactivex.io/RxJS/ like `Observable.of(...)`

Comment: specifically a function that returns an Observable. When I go to that link you posted and I click create, the following page is very confusing. Can you please offer a fiddle or plknr that demonstrates a function that returns an Observable with RxJs v5? In v4 , I had it working with new Observable but I do not know the equivalent with v5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a set of methods to create observables for different use cases:

- **of** - create an observable and directly trigger an event with the provided value
- **timeout** - create an observable that triggers an event after an amount of time
- **interval** - create an observable that triggers repeatly after an amount of time

This link provides a list of them by category:

- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/categories.md

Comment: which one do I use if the caller simply needs to subscribe? Where in the function definition do I put the observer.next( ... ) and the observer.complete() ? My use case is that I want the caller to invoke my function and wait until that function completes so that, when it completes, the caller can then run a block of code found in the subscribe ( ... ) ..  Basically I am trying to replicate returning $q as we did with Angular 1

Comment: How does your function notify that its processing has ended?

Comment: currently, with RxJS v4 new Observable, it notifies that its processing has finished by calling observer.next( responseargs );         observer.complete(); But i have found this convention is not compatible with forkJoin so I am trying to find the RxJS v5 way to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "not compatible"? Here is a plunkr describing how to use a raw observable with `Observable.forkJoin`: https://plnkr.co/edit/XqHYTqL2BadyVltajVhs?p=preview.

Comment: thnx - what I needed was this: return Observable.create((observer) => {

            ...

            observer.next("test");
            observer.complete();

Comment: also, after some testing, I noticed that you have to return something in the next( ... ) arglist in order for the asynch to work