# rxjs with angular2: into component class how to convert input field data changes to rxjs stream

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, angular2-forms, rxjs5

Its said that we can convert anything into stream using rxjs, here i want to convert the data coming from input field into stream and later subscribe to it, there is method in angular2 for this using valueChanges event

```
this.input.valueChanges.subscribe( 
   (value: string) => { console.log('sku changed to: ', value); } 
);
```

but when Im trying to create stream in component class like this

```
Observables.create().subscribe()
```

the create is not recognized, also how can i do this in rxjs as value changes into input field, its related to angular2 forms, also what is useful function to create stream for this

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800792/how-do-you-return-new-observablefunctionobserver-with-rxjs-v5?noredirect=1#comment59272278_35800792

Comment: no i know how to create stream but problem is Observables.create giving error in the component class like its not allowed in class to create, how can i make avaliable it into component class

Comment: move it into a function

Comment: `this.input.valueChanges` is already an `Observable<string>` that you can `subscribe()` to in order to get the stream of changes.  What is your actual question?

Comment: I find that using a `Subject` works great.  For example: `var stream = new Subject<string>(); stream.next("some changes");` Of course, you have to `import Subject`. The `Subject` is an `Observable` that can be subscribed to.

Answer (score 4):

Angular 2 already have a [FormControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) which exposes a valueChanges observable that you can subscribe to.

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qArvr87MqSxQXoYneUmT?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts) and the code:

The important parts are:
 - [FormControl]="model"  (in the input element)
 - model = new FormControl()   (from @angular/forms)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      Some Value: 
      <input type="text" [formControl]="model" />
      <div>{{model.value}}</div>
      <span *ngFor="let val of values">{{val}},</span>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  model:FormControl = new FormControl()
  values = [];
  constructor() {
    this.model.valueChanges.subscribe(s=>this.values.push(s));
  }
}
```

Also, in your AppModule you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule`

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [...],
    bootstrap: [...]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: link to NgFormControl  is dead, Control is also not found

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem but you can create a raw stream with the `Observable` class and its create method like this:

```
var observable = Observable.create((observer) => {
  // Should be execute asynchronously
  observer.next('some event');
});
```

In Angular2, the `valueChanges` observable allows to initiate an asynchronous processing chain. You can leverage operators like `flatMap` to link another observable. For example to execute an HTTP request when the value of an input changes:

```
var observable = this.input.valueChanges
            .flatMap((val) => {
              return this.http.get('http://...').map(res => res.map();
            });
```

Comment: I know about create method, problem is in the component class where i want write code to detect change into particular field's value using observable is not allowed, its allowed outside component class

Comment: What isn't exactly allowed in your component class? Just want to correctly understand your problem...

Comment: Why is the use of `Observable.create` not possible in your component class? See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/XqHYTqL2BadyVltajVhs?p=preview.