# Angular 2 Observable.forkJoin with for loop

Tags: angular, rest, typescript

This is how i am working now:

```
getTwoObjectById(url1: string, id1: string, url2: string, id2): any{
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get(url1 + `/${id1}`, this.jsonWebToken()).map(res => 
      res.json()),
    this.http.get(url2 + `/${id2}`, this.jsonWebToken()).map(res => 
      res.json())
  );
}
```

I want to prevent this kind of function with id1, url1, id2, url2, id3, url3...

I am trying to write a function that should take as params an Array of IDs and an Array of URLs. With `Observable.forkJoin` the for loop should execute each request getById to Backend-URL that are in Array.
My problem is by the for loop

```
getObjectsById(ids: Array<string>, urls: Array<string>): Observable<any>{
  return Observable.forkJoin(

  for(let i = 0; i++; i<ids.length) {

     this.http.get(urls[i] + `/${ids[i]}`, this.jsonWebToken()).map(res => res.json());

  }

 )
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Observable.forkJoin and array argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676451/observable-forkjoin-and-array-argument)

Answer (score 7):

Try using this

```
inputObject = [1, 2, 3, 4];


getObjectsById() {
    let observableBatch = [];

    this.inputObject.forEach((key) => {
      observableBatch.push(this.http.get(url+key).map((res) => res.json()));
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
  }
```