# RxJs Angular 7 HttpClient multiple POST with forkJoin remove second subscribe?

Tags: angular, loops, rxjs, observable

I am creating a Work Item object with linked child Task objects.  My function (createWorkItemAndChildren) takes two parameters, the workItem, and an array of Task objects.  I want my function to return an array of all ids that are created (work item and tasks).

I have to have the parent ID back from one http POST call (workItemService.createWorkItem) before I can then create the child tasks which use another http POST method on the same service.

I now have the forkJoin in createChildWorkItems returning all of the child ids at once.

How do I refactor this so that there is only one subscribe, and to return the array with parent and child ids together?

```js
  createChildWorkItems(parentId, tasks: Task[]): Observable<any> {
    return <Observable<number>> forkJoin(
      tasks.map(task => <Observable<number>> this.workItemService.createChildWorkItem(parentId, task))
    ).pipe(zip());

  }

  createWorkItemAndChildren(workItem, childTasksToSave: Task[]){
    var resultArray = [];
    this.workItemService.createWorkItem(workItem).subscribe(workItemId => {
      var parentId = workItemId;
      resultArray.push(parentId);
      if (parentId !== null){
        this.createChildWorkItems(parentId, childTasksToSave).subscribe((results: number) => {
          resultArray.push(results);
          this.tfsIdsCreated = resultArray;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do subtasks in parallel — [**forkJoin**](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/forkJoin/) is your choice.

Heres a rough example:

```js
createParent().pipe(
  // switch from parent stream to forkJoin(...children)
  mergeMap(parent =>
    // wait for all children to be created
    forkJoin(children.map(child => createChild(parent, child))).pipe(
      // combine childResults with parent
      map(childResults => {
        // do operations with parent and all children
        parent.childResults = childResults;
        // switch back to parent
        return parent;
      })
    )
  )
)
.subscribe(parent => {
  // ...
})
```

*Note how we subscribe to Observable only once — this is a good practice.*

You don't need `async await` here.

Hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I am still having some issues understanding how to adapt my code to this.  In your createParent() example code, is that returning an observable, or just a number?

Comment: @JenniferS, `createParent()` should return Observable, similar to your  `this.workItemService.createWorkItem`. Here, I've compiled a small example, closer to your code: [mergeMap with forkJoin](https://thinkrx.io/gist/382aab1cc645b933e23c800f784b09aa)

Comment: Thanks for this extra effort to explain. But what is the rxObserver doing?

Comment: @JenniferS It's a part of the chart API to render those marble diagrams. It implements [Observer](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/Observer) interface, so you can substitute it with `x=>console.log(x)` if you want it to output to console instead.

Comment: @JenniferS, glad to hear that :) GL

Answer (score 2):

In your situation child is not good candidate for fork join. but here you should use  Async /await.  fork join send the request in Async manner but Async/await will wait response of each request when you get response attach that response to parent simple, 
in Async/await request will be in  sequeance just like loop. when all request done, return that object 
here is link of asyn/await https://lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795/

```
  createWorkItemAndChildTasks(workitem, childTasksToSave: Task[]): any {
    this.workItemService.createWorkItem(workitem).subscribe(workItemId => {
     var parentId = workItemId;
      if (parentId !== null ){
        this.tfsIdsCreated.push(parentId);

    // now create the children on the workItemForm.
    for (let child of childTasksToSave){
//use here Async await when you get response attach to parent 

     this.workItemService.createChildWorkItem(parentId, child).subscribe(task =>{
        if (task !== null){
          console.log(' createWorkItem received child taskid: ' + task);
          this.tfsIdsCreated.push(task);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  return this.tfsIdsCreated;
});
```

}

Comment: How does the syntax change for the async await?

Comment: add async keyword to  createWorkItemAndChildTasks try this .. 
async  createWorkItemAndChildTasks(workitem, childTasksToSave: Task[]){
//  
 for (let child of childTasksToSave){

    const task =  fetchChild(parentId, child);
   
        if (task !== null){
          console.log(' createWorkItem received child taskid: ' + task);
          this.tfsIdsCreated.push(task);
        }
      
    }
}
async fetchChild(parentId, child){
  const response = await  this.workItemService.createChildWorkItem(parentId, child).toPromise();
    return response;

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of observables and pass the reference into forkjoin

```
let observableBatch= [];

for (let child of childTasksToSave){
   observableBatch.push(this.workItemService.createChildWorkItem(parentId, child));
}

Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch).subscribe...;
```

reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676917/6651984

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing, which is why I accepted the answer from kos :
My tfsIdsCreated array is subscribing to the result, which is providing the list of ids.

```
createParentAndKids(workItem, childTasksToSave){
    this.workItemService.createWorkItem(workItem).pipe(
      mergeMap(parentId => {
        if (parentId === null){
          return of([parentId]);
        }

        const childTaskObservables$ = childTasksToSave.map(
          child => this.workItemService.createChildWorkItem(parentId, child)
        );

        return forkJoin(childTaskObservables$).pipe(
          map(ids => [parentId, ...ids])
        );

      })
    ).subscribe(x => this.tfsIdsCreated.push(x));
  }
```